# selectfromresult rtk always undefined

Tags: react-redux, redux-thunk, rtk-query

// id comes from route and i use rtk query hook
but inquiry always be undefined and i log the data from useGetInquiriesQuery IT WORKS
WHAT IS THE BEST WAY TO DO

```
const { id } = useParams();
const validate = (input = values) => {
}
const [values, setValues, errors, setErrors, inputChanged] = useForm(initstate, validate)
const {inquiry} =useGetInquiriesQuery(undefined,{
    selectFromResult:({data}) =>({
        inquiry:data?.find((i)=> i.orderId === id),
    }),
})

useEffect(()=>{
    if(inquiry){
        console.log(inquiry)
    }
    
},[inquiry])
```